# Vagrant VirtualBox second disk path

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, disk, provider

I have Vagrant + VirtualBox.

In my Vagrantfile I have

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize [ "createhd", "--filename", "disk", "--size", 100000 ]
    v.customize [ 'storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "disk"]
end
```

When I fire up with vagrant up it looks for "disk" in 
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin\disk

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find file for the medium 'C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin\disk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
```

I would like the disk to live alongside the virtual machine's first disk in 
C:\Users\jma47\VirtualBox VMs\bin_build_1389371691

How can I do this in Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done if you define a name for virtual machine:

```
# Try to make it work on both Windows and Linux
if (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  vboxmanage_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe"
else
  vboxmanage_path = "VBoxManage" # Assume it's in the path on Linux
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/wheezy64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "VM Name"

    # Get disk path
    line = `"#{vboxmanage_path}" list systemproperties`.split(/\n/).grep(/Default machine folder/).first
    vb_machine_folder = line.split(':', 2)[1].strip()
    second_disk = File.join(vb_machine_folder, vb.name, 'disk2.vdi')

    # Create and attach disk
    unless File.exist?(second_disk)
      vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', second_disk, '--format', 'VDI', '--size', 60 * 1024]
    end
    vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 0, '--device', 1, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', second_disk]
  end
end
```

Comment: Any chance to make getting default machine folder portable, i.e. working also on Windows?

Comment: To use this in Windows, run your vagrant up command from cygwin.

Comment: To make it portable change this line: `line = \`vboxmanage list systemproperties\`.split(/\n/).grep(/Default machine folder/).first`

Comment: I found this didn't quite work, because 1) I didn't have VBoxManage in the path and 2) it split the path at the : in "C:\...". To fix this:

`vboxmanage_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe"`
then
`line = `"#{vboxmanage_path}" list systemproperties`.split(/\n/).grep(/Default machine folder/).first`
then
`vb_machine_folder = line.split(':', 2)[1].strip()`

Answer (score 8):

You need to use something like this in your Vagrantfile:

For Vagrant API v1:

```
# Where to store the disk file
disk = 'C:\Users\jma47\VirtualBox VMs\bin_build_1389371691\extra_disk.vdi'

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'base'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do | v |
    unless File.exist?(disk)
      config.vm.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disk, '--size', 500 * 1024]
    end
    config.vm.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
  end
end
```

For Vagrant API v2:

```
# Where to store the disk file
disk = 'C:\Users\jma47\VirtualBox VMs\bin_build_1389371691\extra_disk.vdi'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'base'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do | p |
    unless File.exist?(disk)
      p.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disk, '--size', 1 * 1024]
    end
    p.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
  end
end
```

Comment: For anyone else who wanders by here, 'SATA Controller' will change depending on what the box / OS expects. 'SATA' is another common option.

Comment: `==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...` and `Couldn't open file /C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/project/base`

Comment: @Chloe replace `base` with whatever vagrant base box you want to start from, eg. `debian/wheezy64`

Comment: It's an embedded system that I have generated myself. There is no Vagrant base. http://dev.qmp.cat/projects/qmp/wiki/Virtualbox

Comment: I think a box is required for Vagrant - but they're easy to make yourself from an existing VM: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html

Comment: `IDE` instead of `SATA Controller` worked for me on a `Centos/7` box. In general, you can also use the VirtualBox GUI to find out the controller's name in the `Settings->Storage` menu (box needs to be turned off prior to access).

Answer (score 0):

The "disk" parameter should be a path, Virtualbox needs it to store the second disk.

Use an absolute one like "c:\temp.disk" or "/tmp/disk.img"

Comment: Don't prefix the path with redundant  './' either - I've seen an issue with 'tmp/file.vdi' compared to './tmp/file.vdi' which are essentially the same file but cause issues with createhd occasionally duriong vagrant up on a clean install.